# Is there any way to add java script in jmeter using BeanShell PostProcessor

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to connect websocket server using below code.  but not connected.
This is the code which i am using in BeanShell PostProcessor

```
// Create a new WebSocket.
var socket = new WebSocket('wss://api.qa.xyz.io:443');
// Show a connected message when the WebSocket is opened.
socket.onopen = function(event) {
  socketStatus.innerHTML = 'Connected to: ' + event.currentTarget.url;
  socketStatus.className = 'open';
};
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``// Create a new WebSocket. var socket = new WebSocket('wss://api.qa.xyz.io . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 2, column 30.  Encountered: "s" (115), after : "\'w"

Comment: WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``// Create a new WebSocket. var socket = new WebSocket('wss://api.qa.xyz.io . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 2, column 30.  Encountered: "s" (115), after : "\'w"

Comment: Please put your code in try catch and print ex message to find the problem